# How can I get my MultiSelectList to bind to my data model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a many to many relationship between cars and many other tables. In my view I want to be able to have a multiselect list for items such as lights. I've tried many different formats I can't seem to get the list to set selected items.My preferred way to do it would be @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.enitity.relatedentity, Model.SomeSelectListItemList) , but I can not seem to get list to set selected items in the view.

Below is my code I was testing with
I use Asp.net MVC5, C# and entity framework 6.

This is my controller action

```
    // GET: Car/Edit/
    [Authorize(Roles = "Ecar")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {


        CarsEditViewModel carEditViewModel = new CarsEditViewModel();

        carEditViewModel.Cars = unitOfWorkcar.CarRepository.FindIncluding(id);

        IList<Approval> approvalList = unitOfWorkcar.ApprovalRepository.All.ToList();
        IList<Connector> connectorList = unitOfWorkcar.ConnectorRepository.All.ToList();
        IList<InputVoltage> inputVoltagesList = unitOfWorkcar.InputVoltageRepository.All.ToList();



        carEditViewModel.ApprovalList = from c in approvalList select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id.ToString(), Selected = true};

        carEditViewModel.Categories = new MultiSelectList(carEditViewModel.ApprovalList, "Value", "Text", "Selected");


       // ,carEditViewModel.ApprovalList.Select(c => c.Text),carEditViewModel.ApprovalList.Select(c => c.Selected)

        //carEditViewModel.ApprovalList = from c in approvalList select new MultiSelectList( //{ Selected = (carEditViewModel.Cars.Approvals.Any(app => app.Id == c.Id)) , Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id.ToString() };
       // carEditViewModel.ConnectorList = from c in connectorList select new SelectListItem { Selected = true,  Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id.ToString() };
        carEditViewModel.InputVoltageList = from c in inputVoltagesList select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id.ToString() };



        return View(carEditViewModel);

    }
```

Here is my view

```
@model NewBobPortal.ViewModels.CarsEditViewModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{



   @* @Html.ListBoxFor("SelectedApprovals",model => model., new { @class = "multiselect" })*@
    @*@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Cars.Approvals, Model.ApprovalList)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Cars.Connectors,Model.ConnectorList, new {Multiple = "multiple"})
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ConnectorList, Model.ConnectorList)*@
    @*@Html.ListBox("test",Model.Cars.InputVoltages, Model.InputVoltageList)*@
    @Html.DropDownList("somethingelse", new MultiSelectList(Model.InputVoltageList, "Value", "Text", Model.InputVoltageList.Select(c => c.Value)), new { multiple = "multiple" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cars.InputVoltages , new MultiSelectList(Model.LensColorList, "Value", "Text", Model.LensColorList.Select(c => c.Value)), new { multiple = "multiple" })


    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Cars.Approvals, Model.Categories)



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
```

}

This is my viewmodel

```
using NewBobPortal.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace NewBobPortal.ViewModels
 {
public class CarsEditViewModel
{
    public Car Cars { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ApprovalList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MultiSelectList> ConnectorList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> InputVoltageList { get; set; }




    public MultiSelectList Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Approval> SelectedCategories { get; set; }

}
```

}

Answer (score 9):

The biggest problem with posting values for a many-to-many relationship is that there's no direct field to bind to on your model. This is where view models become very handy, which you're already using, but not quite in the right way for this.

First you need your `SelectList`, which can actually just be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. This will contain *all* available options, which is easy enough. So in your view model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryChoices { get; set; }
```

And in your action:

```
carEditViewModel.CategoryChoices = approvalList.Select(m => new SelectListItem {
    Text = c.Name,
    Value = c.Id.ToString()
});
```

Notice that I'm not setting `Selected`: we'll let the HtmlHelper handle that. I'm also not dealing with a `MultiSelectList` yet either.

Now, you'll also need something to post back to, since your values will be ids, we'll use a `List<int>`, so in your view model:

```
private List<int> selectedCategories;
public List<int> SelectedCategories
{
    get
    {
        if (selectCategories == null)
        {
            selectedCategories = Categories.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
        }
        return selectedCategories;
    }
    set { selectedCategories = value; }
}
```

There's a bit going on here. The `set` method of the property is simple: when we get a posted value back, just set `selectedCategories` to that. The `get` is a bit more complicated: here we need to condense down your list of category objects (called `Categories` here because I don't know where this is actually coming from) into a simple list of ids for those categories.

Now, in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCategories, Model.CategoryChoices)
```

That's all you need. You're using a `ListBox` control so it's already a multiple select list. And, by binding it to the list of all currently selected ids, it knows which items to select automatically in the list of `SelectListItem`s it gets from `Model.CategoryChoices`.

In your post action, you then need to translate these ids into their associated objects:

```
 var newCategories = repository.Categories.Where(m => carEditViewModel.SelectedCategories.Contains(m.Id));
```

Then, you can set your model's categories to this new list manually:

```
car.Categories = newCategories;
```

Comment: Chris, that's a pretty awesome answer. I follow what your doing but what specifically allows you to strongly type the parameters for @HTML.ListBoxFor? -Thanks

Comment: `SelectedCategories` and `CategoryChoices` are both properties on the view model, which is then set as the model for the view. `SelectedCategories` is populated with the list of ids of currently associated categories, and `CategoryChoices` is set to the list of all categories. `ListBoxFor` then uses `CategoryChoices` to create a `MultiSelectList` and sets `Selected` on the list items whose value matches the set from `SelectedCategories`.

Comment: For the create method it works create for me.. Though the edit won't work for some reason. is it needed to do something different?
besides setting .State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I am working on this exact same issue.  Getting an error in my view code: `The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedCategories' is of type 'List`1[[System.Int32]]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.  Any ideas?

Comment: @dmikester1: It's hard to say without context. I suggest opening a separate question where you can post your controller, model, and view code.

Comment: thanks!  Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299110/saving-selected-multiselectlist-items-back-to-the-model